# What does each depointer/dereference syntax make the variable mean?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, syntax, reference

EDIT: Since there is no difference between `int * x`, `int* x`, and `int *x`, I removed that section to better clarify what I'm confused about.

## The question:

The differences between "pointers" and "references" are explained in the answer to [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in/57492#57492), but the syntax itself seems to have different meanings depending on the context.

When a pointer or reference is declared, what do the `*` and `&` modifiers make those variables mean later?  Are they the pointer, the raw value, the object reference, etc.

For example, since words seem to be failing me here:

```
void foo(int* x, int& y) {
    assert(*x == ??);
    assert(&x == ??);
    assert(*y == ??);
    assert(&y == ??);
}
```

Comment: maybe you got confused by a quirk in the grammar that makes `int * x,y;` declare an `int*` and an `int`, or I dont know what caused your confusion. Anyhow, where you put the blank does not matter

Comment: *but I can't find a hard explanation of what happens when a variable is declared with these modifiers in a method* The exact same thing.  A declaration is a declaration, it doesn't matter where it is, it still follows the single set of declaration rules C++ has.

Comment: `int* x` is the same as `int *x` is the same as `int * x`.  Same for the references `&` .

Comment: You don't get a pointer with `*x` and a reference with `&x`, you get an error with `*x` for trying to dereference an `int` and you get a pointer with `&x` because `&x` takes the address of `x` and the value of a pointer is an address.

Comment: "*if you have a variable declared with int x, you can get the pointer with *x and the reference with &x*" No. If you have a pointer `int* x` then you can have the value this pointer points to by `value= *x;` A pointer is basically an address. If you have a value `x` then you can get its address by `address= &x;`

Comment: To be clear, `*` and `&` have different meanings in declarations vs. expressions. Declaring something as a pointer is not the same as dereferencing a variable that's already been declared. I'm not sure if that's what you're stuck on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for this are pretty simple.  It does not matter where you see a declaration, if it is in `main`, `some_namespace`, inside a class, or in the parameter section of a function, a declaration means the same thing.  Knowing that, whenever you see

```
type_name * variable_name
```

you are declaring a pointer.  Wherever you see

```
type_name & variable_name
```

You are declaring a reference.  The spacing here doesn't matter, `int* foo`, `int * foo`, and `int *foo` all declare an `int*` named `foo`.  The only tricky bit here is that the `*` or `&` applies to the variable name, not the type.  That means in code like

```
int * foo, bar;
```

`foo` and `bar` are not both pointers.  `foo` is a pointer  to an `int` and `bar` is just an `int`.  To make `bar` and `int` you'd need to use

```
int * foo, * bar;
```

And that take care of declarations.

For use, if you see

```
*variable_name
```

Then you are indirecting through `variable_name` (calling the unary `operator*`).  If you see

```
&variable_name
```

then you are getting the address of `variable_name`, or calling `operator&` of the `variable_name`'s type.